# How to put a linux command output into this json string in aws cli?

Tags: zsh

I want to be able to use aws cli to update a row in dynamodb and change value of some of its fields.

One of them is a boolean. The other is a number field which contains the unix timestamp.

```
aws --profile dev dynamodb update-item  --table-name my-dyno-table  \
  --update-expression "SET deleted = false, updated = :updated" \
  --expression-attribute-value '{":updated": {"N":`date +%s`}' \
  --key '{ ":s1": { "S": "83418294-eae0-4f90-ad56-3972e8c12a0d"}}' \
  --endpoint-url http://localhost:7070
```

I can obtain the time stamp by running `date +%s`.

However, as you can see in my aws cli command above, I have trouble getting the date output into

```
'{":updated": {"N":`date +%s`}'
```

The zsh complaints

> Error parsing parameter '--expression-attribute-values': Invalid JSON:
> Expecting value: line 1 column 19 (char 18) JSON received:
> {":updated": {"N":`date +%s`}

What is the proper way to get the `date` value into this string?

Answer (score 1):

My problem was I that I had put them in a pair of single qoutes.

Here is a solution:

```
"{\":updated\": {\"N\":`date +%s`}}"
```